# Bazel Build does not compile libraries from GITLab CI Job (Docker container)

Tags: c++, docker, gitlab, bazel

I am performing a simple c++ compile of my project using Bazel 5.3.0. from a Docker image running in a GITLab Ci Job. I am able to compile successfully on my host by running:

```
docker exec -it pdi-container /bin/bash -c "bazel build --config-cpp_config //main:verify_tool"
```

However, when I compile this project from GitLab I receive the below error from GITLab:

```
 bazel --output_base output build --genrule_strategy=standalone --spawn_strategy=standalone -- 
 verbose_failures --sandbox_debug --config=cpp_config //main:verify_tool
 Loading: 
 Loading: 0 packages loaded
 Analyzing: target //main:verify_tool (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
 INFO: Analyzed target //main:verify_tool (0 packages loaded, 6 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
[0 / 3] [Prepa] BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt 
[3 / 8] Compiling main/pm.cpp; 1s local ... (4 actions running)
[3 / 8] Compiling main/pm.cpp; 11s local ... (4 actions running)
ERROR: /builds/avsw/programs/new_shepard/PDI/pdi-verify-tool/main/BUILD:3:10: Compiling 
main/process_verify_data_helper.cpp failed: (Exit 1): g++ failed: error executing command 
  (cd /builds/avsw/programs/new_shepard/PDI/pdi-verify-tool/output/execroot/__main__ && \
  exec env - \
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin \
    PWD=/proc/self/cwd \
  /usr/bin/g++ -MD -MF bazel-out/64-fastbuild/bin/main/_objs/verify_tool/process_verify_data_helper.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/64- fastbuild/bin/main/_objs/verify_tool/process_verify_data_helper.o' -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/64-fastbuild/bin -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/64-fastbuild/bin/external/bazel_tools -g -Wall -Werror '-std=c++17' - I/usr/include/jinja2cpp/include -I/usr/local/include/boost -c main/process_verify_data_helper.cpp -o bazel-out/64-fastbuild/bin/main/_objs/verify_tool/process_verify_data_helper.o)# Configuration: 757e432bd578388925ee038e81d419bbf7bedee5ead3ef18301b28a7f1139389 # Execution platform: @local_config_platform//:host g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus compilation terminated.Target //main:verify_tool failed to build
```

The only difference is I am building the project from GITLab CI. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can see its fixed here https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-discuss/c/hRCYQBZCK5U/m/AXa1oq3MBQAJ

Comment: yes, this is fixed. I will mark it as resolved